# pip does not find the version of the package to install

Tags: python, pip

I want to install [pytorch3d](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch3d/#history) version 0.3.0 or above, but pip sees only 0.0.1 version for installing. I runned next commands:

```
pip install pytorch3d==0.3.0
```

And got the next error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch3d==0.3.0 (from versions: 0.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch3d==0.3.0
```

If I run the install command without a specific version, pip will install the package with version 0.0.1.

My environment:

- Windows 10 x64
- Python 3.9.7
- pip 21.2.4

Note:

- direct internet connection, no proxy used
- I haven't others versions python on pc
- same errors when installing next packages: `torchvision==0.7.0, torch==1.6.0`
- I tried with the virtualenv and without them
- I installed Python from the windows store.

Comment: All versions on PyPI except 0.0.1 have incomplete metadata. You can try to install from github, by checking the project out and running `python setup.py install`. Or you can just give the link to download a zip to `pip`.

Comment: From pytorch3d install instructions, `pip install pytorch3d` is only available for macOS: https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d/blob/main/INSTALL.md#2-install-from-pypi-on-mac-only. Their pypi page only has wheels for macOS: https://pypi.org/project/pytorch3d/#files. Check their install README for other options for Windows: https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d/blob/main/INSTALL.md#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specified package cannot be installed via pip, because not supported on my os(Windows 10). This can be seen on the [page with the version](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch3d/0.3.0/#files) and available files for download of the required package.

Answer (score 0):

From their installation [guide](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d/blob/main/INSTALL.md) and your requirements use:

```
pip install pytorch3d -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/pytorch3d/packaging/wheels/py38_cu102_pyt190/download.html
```

Comment: This is for Linux, and running for that command it will install the pytorch3d of 0.0.1 version (in my case).

Comment: That version seems only available for linux and macos so far, you are right that insalling will only roll to the 0.0.1 version, check from pip wheels download section for that [version](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch3d/0.3.0/#modal-close)

on comparison to [version 0.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch3d/0.0.1/#files) it provides any platform support, including windows

Comment: A workaround is to clone the repo and install it manually on a virtualenv: 
  virtualenv venv, 
  source venv/Scripts/activate, 
   git clone pytorch3d repo, 
   cd pytorch3d, 
   python3 setup.py install

Comment: you're right, thanks, while clone and install from repo I got another error "No module named 'torch", but I tried installing a package via WSL and didn't get any error.